# Create a multi-labelled dataset from a redundant binary one for multi-label classification

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multilabel-classification

I'm given a dataset (dataframe) of the sort:

```
x   y

A   a
A   b
B   c
C   g
B   g
```

Here's what I need for multi-label classification-

```
x   y

A   a,b
B   c,g
C   g
```

How should I go about it?

Comment: If there is a reason why you unaccepted my answer, please let me know and I can address the issue.

Comment: @piRSquared MultiLabelBinarizer cannot inherently process the way output is generated by your solution. df.groupby("Id").Class.apply(list) is what I needed.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  For future reference, when you state that you want `a,b` in a column element, it's assumed that is a comma separated string.  Had you wanted lists and had said so, I could have easily provided lists.  We usually represent lists in this way `[a, b]`  I hope you understand how we came to this misunderstanding.... Good luck.

Comment: @piRSquared Apologies. Will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Use `groupby` with `','.join`

```
df.groupby('x').y.apply(','.join).reset_index()

   x    y
0  A  a,b
1  B  c,g
2  C    g
```

**Option 2**
Use `pivot_table` with `','.join`

```
df.pivot_table('y', 'x', aggfunc=','.join).reset_index()

   x    y
0  A  a,b
1  B  c,g
2  C    g
```